# Spring form:option

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any way to mark an option as selected by default, much like the `selected` attribute in the `HTML option` tag like `<option value="value1" selected>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the path value of the tag matches the value of options value it will automatically be selected. You don't need anything special

Comment: I understand that, but some business logic needs me to have a default selected item the first time it loads (subsequent loads, select list goes away and is replaced by a hidden field).

Comment: Set that as the default value for that field in command object.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to mark an option as selected by default ???

Just use <spring:option Taglib **The first one will be automatically selected**

```
<spring:select name="someProperty">
    <spring:option value="">Select one</spring:option>
    <spring:option value="someValue">Some value<spring:select>
    <!--And so on...-->
<spring:select>
```

or

```
<spring:select name="someCollection">
    <spring:option value="">Select one</spring:option>
    <!--Here goes some List added to request-->
    <spring:options itemLabel="propertyNameUsedAsLabel" itemValue="propertyNameUsedAsValue"/>
    <!--And so on...-->
<spring:select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are also using Spring MVC.  If you have business logic that requires a certain option to be selected by default, move that business logic to the controller - not the JSP.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");

        // first we need to give the countries list to the model
        model.addObject("countries", countryService.getAllCountries());

        // creating the form
        ExampleForm form = new ExampleForm(); 

        // setting the default to Germany (de)             
        form.setCountryCode = "de";
        // adding the form (with the default country set) to the model
        model.addObject("form", form);

        return model;
}
```

In the JSP, we pass in the countries to the options and spring will automatically have germany selected:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="form">

    <%-- other fields ... --%>

    <form:select path="countryCode">
        <form:options items="${countries}" itemValue="countryCode" itemLabel="countryName"/>
    </form:select>

    <%-- other fields ... --%>

</form:form>
```